# Is there any best practices or conventions for ios project structure

Tags: ios, xcode, naming-conventions, directory-structure, conventions

I was wondering if there is any best practices or conventions to structure your iOS projects?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a little vague, which is why I don't think anyone's answered yet. Do you mean the actual files in the project and the directories they go in? Do you mean the architecture of the code? Etc.

Comment: @quixoto - I am mainly concerned about how to manage different files in different directories.

Answer (score 9):

Taken from [iOS Coding Best Practices](http://de.slideshare.net/jldavid/ios-coding-best-practices-12969046) Slideshare from Jean-Luc David:

[image]

Comment: It absolutely depends on how much code you have in your project, but I personally think that a folder named "Helpers" is not that good. There is a risk that everything eventually will end up in there, as long as it is considered to be a "utility". I think that separate folders with self-explanatory names for separate kind of utilities are better, like "Encryption", "Serialization" etc.

Comment: A Helper/Utility-Package is a common approach to extract functionality which is reusable and is most likely to be put into a reusable Utility-Library some day. Of course there are self-explanatory folders within the Helper/Utility-Package but I wouldn't recommend to put them on the same level like your Model or Controller package especially in a big project… But as it is all a matter of taste, it is most important to agree with your team on one basic structure you all feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 4):

As for me, [Architecting iOS Project](http://www.slideshare.net/MassimoOliviero/architecting-ios-project) solution works perfectly. I also added Cocoapods.

Now my project looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a similar one to the following for my projects.

But after going through this thread and some other articles online, I decided to categorize few types under a new folder code UI.

- Application (Config file with constants, AppDelegate)
- Models
- **UI**

  - **Views**
  - **Controllers**
  - If I use **Nib files (.Xib)** they should come under this or else the **storyboard**(s)
- Resources (All resources like Images, Custom fonts, Audio files with each in different subfolders)
- Services
- **Helpers/Utilities**
- Libraries

But if you are using MVVM architecture, please customize this to your best fit.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that most common practice is to have files grouped by types (i.e. ViewControllers, Models etc.), I would add that there are some business cases where it is more useful to organize code by provided functionality. For example if you work for company that offers multiple combination of services, usually packed into different apps that share some of elements, for example - AddressBook, Messages, Document Management, etc...

In my projects I usually have a folder called Common where I put things that I reuse often, like datetime helpers, IO writers etc...
Other things I separate by functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**We follow a standard project structure so as the team can understand in a better way.**

[image]